# Multiple insert queries in one stored procedure My Sql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, insert

I had to create many routines (stored procedures) for every query, how can I do the following procedures into one single procedure, same way I need to put around eight procedures like that, any idea could be helpful, thanks in advance.

**Procedure 1**

```
INSERT INTO public_holidays (user_id, department_id,designation_id,date_cur,clock_in,clock_out)
SELECT cl.user_id, des.department_id , us.designation_id, cl.date,cl.clock_in, cl.clock_out
FROM clock cl 
INNER JOIN holidays AS hol ON hol.date = cl.date
INNER JOIN users AS us ON cl.user_id = us.id
INNER JOIN designations AS des ON des.id = us.designation_id
WHERE date(cl.created_at) = cur_dat
AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(second,cl.clock_in, cl.clock_out) = 28800;
```

**Procedure 2**

```
INSERT INTO public_holidays_nine (user_id, department_id,designation_id,date_cur,clock_in,clock_out)
SELECT clo.user_id, design.department_id , uses.designation_id, clo.date,clo.clock_in, clo.clock_out 
FROM clock clo
INNER JOIN holidays AS holl ON holl.date = clo.date
INNER JOIN users AS uses ON clo.user_id = uses.id
INNER JOIN designations AS design ON design.id = uses.designation_id
WHERE date(clo.created_at) = cur_dat
AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(second,clo.clock_in, clo.clock_out) = 32400;
```

Comment: You can use Mode like `@Mode` as a parameter in procedure. and pass it as 1,2,3,... From your code behind. Your condition inside procedure will be `If @Mode=1 Begin query1 End` same for all modes.

Comment: @RahulHendawe any examples sir thank u.

Comment: maybe one problem is that you have tables such as `public_holidays` and `public_holidays_nine` when you should have less, like 1, not 10 (at least perhaps) for those

Comment: @Drew i dont understand?

Comment: Maybe the reason you have so many sp's is because you have too many tables and you shouldn't have too many table. Just maybe.

Comment: oh okk but i need to many tables to maintain the data individually.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_test`(IN _date datetime)
BEGIN
    #Routine body goes here...
INSERT INTO public_holidays (user_id, department_id,designation_id,date_cur,clock_in,clock_out)
SELECT cl.user_id, des.department_id , us.designation_id, cl.date,cl.clock_in, cl.clock_out
FROM clock cl 
INNER JOIN holidays AS hol ON hol.date = cl.date
INNER JOIN users AS us ON cl.user_id = us.id
INNER JOIN designations AS des ON des.id = us.designation_id
WHERE date(cl.created_at) = cur_dat
AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(second,cl.clock_in, cl.clock_out) = 28800;


INSERT INTO public_holidays_nine (user_id, department_id,designation_id,date_cur,clock_in,clock_out)
SELECT clo.user_id, design.department_id , uses.designation_id, clo.date,clo.clock_in, clo.clock_out 
FROM clock clo
INNER JOIN holidays AS holl ON holl.date = clo.date
INNER JOIN users AS uses ON clo.user_id = uses.id
INNER JOIN designations AS design ON design.id = uses.designation_id
WHERE date(clo.created_at) = cur_dat
AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(second,clo.clock_in, clo.clock_out) = 32400;

END
```

You can Call this Procedure as

```
CALL sp_test(param1)
```

Comment: it shows the following error while creating, The following query has failed: "CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `pros`(IN `cur_dat` VARCHAR(40)) NOT DETERMINISTIC NO SQL SQL SECURITY DEFINER INSERT INTO public_holidays. And having only one parameter cur_dat.

Comment: From where you add this procedure? by running script or manually ? what is your dbengine

Comment: by running a script from laravel, DB::statement(DB::raw('CALL public_holidays(?)'),  array($current_date));  my dbengine is InnoDB.

Comment: Here you can passing only one parameter as it expects 6 please check and verify by running procedure in phpmyadmin

Comment: i need to send only one parameter and one parameter works well with one procedure.

Comment: then u need to change my procedure input params

Comment: Change this `CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_test`(IN _test int)`

Comment: my parameter is a date.